# How to configure specific views (reports) in Microsoft Clarity for Moodle?

Tags: moodle, ms-clarity

I recently gained access to Microsoft Clarity for my Moodle learning management environment. I would like to understand the user behavior on each of our pages for the various courses we offer. As most of our courses are self-paced and we don't have many resources to check if users are interacting with non-mandatory activities. I would like to set up specific views on the platform, which I'm calling "reports," to track groups of pages for specific courses.

These reports would be composed of groups of pages, and the idea would be to track these groups. Example:
Report 1 - Course X View of URL A, URL B and URL C.
Report 2 - Course Y View of URL W, URL Z and URL Y.

I have tried to explore the Microsoft Clarity platform to see if I could set up such views or reports. I expected to be able to group pages and create specific reports for each course, but I couldn't find any specific instructions on how to do it. How it is possible to set up those reports?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used MS Clarity, but looks like you can include tags

```
clarity("set", "key", "value");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/filters/custom-tags

You could use Clarity tags in the Moodle code to identify courses in groups, maybe using the course short name or a course custom field